# C# MVC site - saving canvas to an image file on the server - image is being cropped

Tags: javascript, c#, image, canvas

I'm creating an admin system where a user(admin) can create users. The system requires a user to have a photograph.

I've implemented a file upload but I am also trying to provide the option to use a webcam to take an image and use that.

I've pretty much got this working EXCEPT that the image I manage to save on the server is cropped at the bottom.

I assumed it was something to do with the size of the canvas/video elements that I have used. I tried to hard code larger sizes but it had no effect.

In the UI the image is captured from the video element and displayed on the canvas as I want it to be.
I've added a text box that's bound to my Model so I can pass the canvas as text to the server.

Here's the code:

```
<video id='v' class="employee-image-display"></video>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WebcamImageData, new { id = "tbWebcamImage" })
<a class="btn btn-block red" id="btnTakePhoto">
    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
</a>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
function TakePhoto() {

    var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
    //set canvas width/height
    canvas.width = 600;//v.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = 600;//v.videoHeight;

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(v, 0, 0, 600, 600, 0, 0, 600, 600);

    //get image data from canvas
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("img/png");
    imgData = imgData.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");


    $('#tbWebcamImage').val(imgData);

}

function StartWebCam() {
    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                  navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                  navigator.msGetUserMedia);
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia(
           {
               video: true,
               audio: false
           },
 function (stream) {
     var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
     v.src = url ? url.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
     v.play();
 },
 function (error) {
     alert('Something went wrong. (error code ' + error.code + ')');
     return;
 }
        );
    }
    else {
        alert('Sorry, the browser you are using doesn\'t support getUserMedia');
        return;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btnTakePhoto').on('click', function () {
        TakePhoto();
    });
    StartWebCam();
});
```

Controller Action:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.WebcamImageData))
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(bytes);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            string filepath = "~/Content/Images/Employees/test.png";

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(filepath), bytes);
        }
    } 
}
```

[image: Cropped Image]

As you can see - the image is cropped (you should be able to see my chest as in the image below). Here is what the UI looks like when I click the "Take Photo" button:

[image: No Crop.]

As you can see - Not cropped.

Can anyone tell me why my image is being cropped? - is the error client or server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which browser are you using?

Try the following to set the video and canvas dimensions correctly.

```
var v = document.getElementById('v');
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var canvasWidth = 600;
var canvasHeight = 600;

// Wait until the video stream can play
v.addEventListener('canplay', function (e) {
    if (!isStreaming) {
        // videoWidth isn't always set correctly in all browsers
        if (v.videoWidth > 0) {
            canvasHeight = v.videoHeight / (v.videoWidth / canvasWidth)
        }
        v.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
        v.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
        c.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
        c.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
        isStreaming = true;
    }
}, false);
```

Also make your code more cross browser friendly...

```
// Cross browser
navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    // Request access to video only
    navigator.getUserMedia(
                {
                    video: true,
                    audio: false
                },
                function (stream) {
                    // Cross browser checks
                    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    v.src = url ? url.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
                    // Set the video to play
                    v.play();
                },
                function (error) {
                    alert('Something went wrong. (error code ' + error.code + ')');
                }
    );
}
else {
        alert('Sorry, the browser that you are using isn\'t supported.');
        return;
     }
```

**EDIT:** For the context try the following:

```
var con = c.getContext('2d');
con.drawImage(v, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using Chrome but I'll test in others and let you know - I'll also test using your code.

Comment: @Rick See edit... In my experience Chrome can be a pig, FireFox for the win!

Comment: cheers- I'll try the edit too. I just tested in Firefox and the image doesn't get rendered to the canvas when I click the button. I'll convert to your code now and test.

Comment: where does `isStreaming` come from?

Comment: I commented out `isStreaming` and the `if(videoWidth > 0)` part - and it works in Firefox - still getting cropped in Chrome though unfortunately!! I'm gonna try a few things out and will report back if I can get it working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My bad soz... var isStreaming = false; just a variable so that it doesn't attempt to restream video if it is already streaming or the user could have their browser set to allways allow streaming so when the page loads it streams automagically... sweet and good luck! Also if (v.videoWidth > 0) is used by many... I don't fully understand why but it works for me... see http://html5hub.com/using-the-getusermedia-api-with-the-html5-video-and-canvas-elements/